# Get /users/id/insights/used returns no data

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

The API [`/users/id/insights/used`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/insights_list_used) returns no data when executed for a user, which does have some audit logs, showing access and modifications to files for example.

Also, it seems that there is currently no API to retrieve the audit logs, which is what I wanted to do in the first place.

I thought the `/insights` API could be used as kind of an alternative since I was only interested in the logs regarding accessing/modifying files.

Is there maybe another way to do this (retrieving the audit logs) with Microsoft Graph?

Comment: did you execute the query under the beta branch? For me https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/87d349ed-44d7-43e1-9a83-5f2406dee5bd/insights/used does return data in the Graph Explorer(https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Comment: Hi!
Yes I did, the request itself worked, got 200 and [] as a response.
I´m just wondering, why the Activities from the audit logs are not listed in the response.

Answer (score 1):

Insights is an AI-driven process and not the equivalent to an audit log.

From your description, you most likely want [`/reports/getOneDriveActivityUserDetail`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/reportroot_getonedriveactivityuserdetail). There are a couple of different [OneDrive activity reports](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/onedrive_activity_reports) that may also fit what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I thought so and checked that as well, sadly it also just returns empty [].

Comment: Sorry not an empty [] but the csv file contains just 0 values for Viewed Or Edited File Count. But I checked it again today, now it shows some values for March 8th which have not been there on the 9th. So there seems to be a little delay.

Comment: There is a delay but it seems to differ between reporting endpoints. I've typically find everything shows up within 24hrs.